# XSLT Transform UL to SELECT

Tags: xslt

need your help with the following... how transform this:

```
<ul>
    <li value="xxx">Text XXX</li>
    <li value="zzz">Text ZZZ</li>
    <li value="yyy">Text YYY</li>
</ul>
```

to this

```
<select>
    <option value="xxx">Text XXX</option>
    <option value="zzz">Text ZZZ</option>
    <option value="yyy">Text YYY</option>
</select>
```

Thank you in advance.

I tried something that is very far from being correct

```
<xsl:for-each select="ul/li">
    <option value="*/@value">
        <xsl:copy-of select="li"/>
    </option>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your current attempt.

Comment: I am not really good in  and tried total crap. I am ashamed to post what I tried.

Comment: Put it in your question not a comment, besides that's already reasonably close

Answer (score 1):

It is straight-forward with templates:

```
<xsl:template match="ul">
  <select>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </select>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li">
  <option value="{@value}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </option>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call your attempt "total crap", it's actually pretty close. What you need to change is:

1. Put `{}` around values if you want to interpolate them into arguments
2. To access an attribute on the current element you just need `@value`, no `*/`
3. To get the text of the current element you can use `value-of` and `.` to refer to the current element.

Like this:

```
<select>
  <xsl:for-each select="ul/li">
    <option value="{@value}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </option>
  </xsl:for-each>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, man. I used code you gave me and appreciate your explanations.